# Maximal solution, definition interval $]T^-,T^+[$, $y' = f(y)$ with $f$ is $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and the following Cauchy's problem :

$$\begin{cases}
y' = f(y)  \\ 
y(0) = y_0
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is $C^1$ with finite numbers of zeros $x_1 < ... < x_N$.

We suppose $f(x) > 0$ for $x > x_N$. Let $y_0 > x_N$.

First, I have to show that the maximal solution $u$ of the system is defined on ]$-\infty,T^+[$. Secondly, I have to show that $T^+ < \infty$ if and only if $1/f$ is integrable in infty.

I've done : We have $f(x) > 0$, so $u(t)$ is increasing.
Then $y_o > x_N$ therefore $u(t) > x_N$ also.
In this way, $u$ is increasing and lower bounded by $x_N$, defined on $]T-,T+[$. Hence, $T^- = -\infty$.

But how to show the second point ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is $u$? A careful answer of that question should tell you what $T^+$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the function
$$
F(y) := \int_{y_0}^y \frac{1}{f(s)}\, ds,
\qquad y \in J := (x_N, +\infty),
$$
your solution $u\colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ is implicitly defined by the relation
$F(u(t)) = t$ for those values of $t$ belonging to the image of $F$.

Hence $u$ is defined on the interval $(T^-, T^+)$ with
$$
T^- := \int_{y_0}^{x_N} \frac{1}{f(s)}\, ds \in [-\infty, 0),
\qquad
T^+ := \int_{y_0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{f(s)}\, ds \in (0, +\infty].
$$
As you have already observed, the first generalized integral diverges to $-\infty$, since $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous.

The second integral may converge to a finite value (for example if $f(s) \sim s^\alpha$ with $\alpha > 1$ as $s\to +\infty$) or may diverge to $+\infty$ (for example if $f$ is sublinear).

Comment: Thank you so much ! And if $f(x) < 0$ and $y_0 < x_1$, $T^- = \int_{-\infty}^{y_0} \dfrac{1}{f(s)} ds$ and $T^+ = \int_{x_1}^{y_0} \dfrac{1}{f(s)} ds$, is it ?

Comment: In this case the map $F$ above is defined and strictly decreasing in $(-\infty, x_1)$, so $(T^-, T^+) = (F(x_1), F(-\infty))$ (with $F(-\infty) = \lim_{y\to -\infty} F(y)$).

Comment: Okay, I understand :) Thank you.